# Is it possible to have an inverted git subtree, where the dependency lives across multiple folders and the 'owning' repo has one?

Tags: git

I have two git repositories, and I'm having trouble finding a good workflow for managing them. The `upstream` repository is a generic framework. The other repository (`B` extends `upstream` with changes in one folder. Both repos have a steady stream of changes. (This is a generic Gatsby starter, with `B` being a second repo for my site-specific content.)

If I use a normal git `merge` flow to bring upstream into my repo, I end up with lots of conflicts every time I sync my repo with `upstream`, and merge commits polluting my history. I'm happier with `rebase`, but then I have to force push, manually re-order the commits to interleave them, and the timestamp of all commits since the common ancestor gets set to the most recent activity, which is far from ideal.

A git `subtree` or submodule seems almost like what I want, but it's backwards. A subtree lets you insert a dependency (upstream) as a single subfolder in another repo (`B`). In my case, upstream has lots of folders and files all over, and all the interesting stuff in `B` is in just one folder, `content`. I could filter `B` down to just `/content`, make a third repo, `C`, and use it to combine `upstream` and `B`'s `/content`, but then I'd have to push changes to `B` before testing them with the rest of the framework.

[image: file structure and relationship between upstream and B repos]

Is there a way to make this work in a natural way?

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I gave up. I created two `content` directories, one inside the main gatsby hierarchy, and one outside. Within the gatsby framework, I then used conditional imports to decide which `content` to use.
[image]
My `gatsby-config.js` has this at the top:

```
const contentDir = require("fs").existsSync("../content") ? "../content" : "./content";

const config = require(`${contentDir}/meta/config`);
```

In other files which used the content directory, I put a helper abstraction in between:

```
let config;
try {
  config = require("../../../content/meta/config");
} catch (error) {
  config = require("../../content/meta/config");
}

module.exports = config;
```

The git workflow then ended up being a fairly standard subtree one. I set up the 'downstream' repository by doing a git filter to get only the `content` directory:

```
git filter-repo --path content
```

and then did

```
git remote add platform git@github.com:<upstream-gatsby-framework-repo>
git subtree add --prefix platform platform main
```

To update with new platform changes, I run

```
git fetch platform
git subtree pull --prefix platform platform main
git push
```